# How to create enml using EnmlWriter

Tags: evernote

I want to create the below code using enmlwriter:

```
<en-note>  
    <span style="font-weight:bold;color:red;">Here's some bold red text!</span>  
</en-note>
```

But this below code did not work, I need help.

```
Function NewNoteWriter() As ENMLWriter
    Dim writer As New ENMLWriter
    writer.WriteStartDocument()
    writer.WriteStartElement("span")
    writer.WriteAttributeString("style", "font-weight:bold;color:red;")
    writer.WriteEndElement()
    writer.WriteEndDocument()
    Return writer
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is there any error message? What happened instead of the expected result?

Comment: “未处理NotImplementedexception”

Comment: On which line of code are you getting the NotImplementedException?

Comment: Thanks for Phill's help。Here is a detailed post：http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139985/how-to-write-the-code-that-conforms-to-the-dtd-specification-using-writeattrib。
Please check it for me，I really need your help。